# What's the function of "that" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, punctuation, clauses, demonstrative

> Notice, **that** with this meaning, the word is an uncountable noun, so you can only say youth, not youths. ([BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/language/askaboutenglish/2010/08/100803_aae_youth.shtml))

Does "**that**" indicate that the whole part afterwards is the objective clause of the verb "notice"? But why there is a comma between "that" and "notice"?

---

Correct: only "that with this meaning, the word is an uncountable noun" is the object/complement of "notice".

Comment: It could be repunctuated: *Notice that, with this meaning, the word is an uncountable noun.*  Notice that the word is an uncountable noun when it has this meaning.

Comment: And you can find it punctuated that way, though it is a matter of choice: https://books.google.com/books?id=6HcZBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA102&dq=%22notice+that+with+the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjj8tnHgOraAhVKMd8KHaszC7UQ6AEINDAC#v=onepage&q=%22notice%20that%20with%20the%22&f=false or https://books.google.com/books?id=jncHBAYe8TkC&pg=PA56&dq=%22notice+that+with+the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjj8tnHgOraAhVKMd8KHaszC7UQ6AEIUTAH#v=onepage&q=%22notice%20that%20with%20the%22&f=false

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I'm familiar with both of the two punctuating ways you gave, while surprised by the BBC "style".

Comment: The placement of the adjunct **with this meaning** between the clause-introducer, **that** and the subject of the clause, **the word**, is an interruption designed to highlight the restrictive condition or proviso *when it has this meaning*. The interruption can be, but need not be, signaled with commas. Commas isolate the phrase.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to challenge the BBC but I would certainly *not put a comma* there to avoid misunderstanding.

Notice what? Yes, you got it right! Here, *'that'* indicates the rest of the part to pay attention to.

A similar pattern is the result from COCAE:

> ***Notice that with*** equal-weighting, the sum of the attribute values in Table I would be 0 for each system and, therefore,...

Comment: I now think only "that with this meaning, the word is an uncountable noun", not the whole part following "that", is the object/complement of "notice".

Answer (score 1):

> *Notice, [that with this meaning, the word is an uncountable noun, so*
>   *you can only say youth, not youths].*

The comma after "notice" is not required.

This is an imperative construction where "notice" is the verb and the bracketed element is a subordinate content clause functioning as complement of "notice".

Traditional grammar treats the *that* clause as direct object of "notice", but modern grammar takes it as a complement.

With only a few minor exceptions, direct objects are always noun phrases, not clauses.

Comment: 1 I think only "that with this meaning, the word is an uncountable noun", not the whole part following "that", is the object/complement of "notice". 2 Would you put a comma between the verb and its complement?

Comment: No, the whole bracketed element is a clause as complement of "notice". Within the clause, there are two adjuncts "with this meaning" and "so you can only say youth, not youths". I already said that the comma is not required.